# Check my PSU math

Tags: power-supply

I have been working on setting up a new Solaris 11 server for home lab use. I plan learning a bit about ZFS and expanding my sysadmin knowledge a bit. (heavy networking background!) Anyways I got the follow components and want to make sure I got the right size PSU.

I picked up a 430W Corsair CX430.

Here are the components and rough estimates

- AMD phenom x4 125 Watt max
- Rosewill RSV-L4500 Black Metal/ Steel

  - 1.0 mm thickness
  - 4U Rackmount Server Chassis
  - 15 Internal Bays, 8 fans - 30 Watt max
- Asus m4A78T-E - was just laying around - Budgeted 50 Watts
- 4 Sticks of DDR3 - 16GB total - 16 Watts max
- 15 SATA HDDs, 1 SSD - 320 Watts max
- 2 IBM M1015 SAS cards - 30 Watts max
- 1 Intel pt/1000 dual nic pci-x 10 watt max

Total: 531 max

But I know the system will never really run anywhere near that load. I plan on using the cool and quiet features provided by the microarch.

Is this PSU sufficient or should I go for more power? (I know my max is over this, I was definitely liberal with my estimation. 20 watts a SATA HDD is pretty generous IMO)

I have a 700watt one sitting around but it is not a green PSU by any means and I am really looking to be efficient as possible as I plan on leaving it up 24/4 and I am fronting the power.

Let me know what you guys think about this set up and if I should do!

Comment: Besides comparing total watts, you should also compare individual voltage rails.  Find a way to *stagger* start the harddrives.  The max current draw on the 12V line by a HDD is when they spin up, so do not allow all drives to spin up at once.

Comment: the IBM m1015 cards support staggering the hdd spin-ups =)